What type of handlebar is this? what's it called?
What type of handlebar is this?
Here are pictures:
 
I know it's commonly known as "Japanese bike handlebar" or "cruiser handlebar" but I was wondering if what is the real term for it.
I was also wondering what's the proper orientation for this type of handlebar? should I set the rise perpendicular to the ground or at the same angle of the headtube?

Not sure about the name, but the ends should be oriented such that your hands rest comfortably on them, without having tho bend the wrist in any weird direction.

Does this answer help?

One common name for handlebars like this is "North Road handlebar". Usually they are set up so that the ends are roughly horizontal but nobody's stopping you from setting them angled or even flipping them upside down.

This was a really big help. Thank you so much!
